# Getting a vertex which is not within the stl file at all

Tags: python, mesh, trimesh

I'm using `trimesh` to find the closest point on a mesh to a given point,

```
closest_vertex, d, face_id = trimesh.proximity.closest_point(mesh, [[-5,100,0]])
```

That's my code for that bit I get an point back from this code and it displays fine on a graph as well. However when I look at the `stl` file to figure out the point index, the point does not exist.

Any help would be awesome!

I expect to find this point in the stl as after all it still is returning the closest point.

Comment: Read it carefully: [tag:STL] Do NOT use for questions about 3D CAD model. Use [stl-format] instead.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://trimsh.org/trimesh.proximity.html#trimesh.proximity.closest_point) :

> Given a mesh and a list of points find the closest point on any triangle.

So it is finding the closest *point* on your trimesh surface, **not** the closest *vertex*. This is why you are not finding the point in your STL file.

To find the nearest vertex, you'll probably need to write a small function for this :

```py
import numpy as np

def find_closest_vertex(mesh, poi):
    idx = np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(mesh.vertices-poi, 2))
    return mesh.vertices[idx, :]
```

Comment: Hey, so that gives me alot of clarity but also arises me a question? So if I had to find the closest point would that be a possibility?

Comment: yes, that would be a possibility. I'm not aware of any function in the trimesh library that would do this, but the code i included in the answer should work.

Comment: also, if this answers your question, please mark the answer as 'accepted'. It helps with the housekeeping of the site :)